# Spring Mongo criteria query with dates

Tags: mongodb, spring-mongo, spring-mongodb

I have a Product pojo with online and offline date

i use the following query to get all the Products where either `online` date is `Null` or either `offline` date is `Null` . But the following query only returns me when `both online and offline date are null`.

```
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where(Product.IS).is(is).andOperator( Criteria.where(Product.OFFLINE_DATE).is(null).orOperator(Criteria.where(Product.ONLINE_DATE).is(null))));
```

Any clues ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the above Query object you are creating mongo query similar to

```
{ "productId" : "1" , "$and" : [ { "offlineDate" :  null  , "$or" : [ { "onlineDate" :  null }]}]}
```

where as you want to query something similar to `{ "productId" : "1" , "$and" : [ { "$or" : [ { "offlineDate" :  null } , { "onlineDate" :  null }]}]}`

Create a Criteria object for orOperator and put it in to andOperator:

```
 Criteria orOperator = new Criteria().orOperator(Criteria.where(Product.OFFLINE_DATE).is(null),
            Criteria.where(Product.ONLINE_DATE).is(null));
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where(Product.IS).is(is).andOperator(orOperator));
```

I hope this helps.